# I have two beans and need to calculate the percentage from one to the other?

Tags: jsf, javabeans, percentage

I have two javabeans which have two numbers, for 8000 and 35000, how can i calculate thei percentage of 8000 to 35000 in jsf

Answer (score 0):

A JavaBean is a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) width getter and setter for its fields. Its fields can be set by a constructor takes the appropriate arguments or later by the setter methods.

```
public class ValueHolder
{
  private double value1;
  private double value2;
  public ValueHolder( double value1_, double value2_ )
  {
    super();
    value1 = value1_;
    value2 = value2_;
  } 

  public double getValue1() { return value1; }  
  public void setValue1( double value1_ ) { value1 = value1_; };
  public double getValue2() { return value2; }  
  public void setValue2( double value2_ ) { value2 = value2_; };
}
```

You can store the values in a common double array (double[]) as well and create indexed accessors (double getValue( int ndx_ ) ).
The JavaBeans does not contain any business logic they are just simple data storages, ENTITIES. The calculation takes place out ther (most of the cases in CONTROLLERS) but now I place in into the main function for simplicity:

```
public class PercentageApp
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    ValueHolder vh = new ValueHolder( 8000, 35000 );
    double percentage = vh.getValue1() / vh.getValue2();
    System.out.println( "Percentage: " + Double.toString( percentage ) );
  }

}
```